# Use of undeclared identifier 'GL_BGRA_EXT' error in iOS 8(Xcode 6)?

Tags: objective-c, unity-game-engine, ios8, xcode6

I am using Unity 4.3.4f1. and untill right now when i was making Builds for iOS they were working fine.
I just upgraded my Xcode from v5.1 to v6. now the same code is giving me error like the following

```
/.Project DIR/Classes/Unity/CMVideoSampling.mm:51:122: Use of undeclared identifier 'GL_BGRA_EXT'
```

can somebody please help me?
thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should try replacing gl.h with glext.h in include statements of the file which contains this error.

Replace the following:-

```
#include <OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h>
```

with this :-

```
 #include <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>
```

your include statements should look like this:-

Previously:-

```
#include "CMVideoSampling.h"
#include "CVTextureCache.h"
#include "GLESHelper.h"
#include <OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h>
#include <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

After replacing:-

```
#include "CMVideoSampling.h"
#include "CVTextureCache.h"
#include "GLESHelper.h"
#include <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>//replace glext.h here
#include <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```